# Ayuda con Python 3 UnicodeDecodeError al recibir bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo que enviar la salida de un comando "ipconfig" utilizando un socket con el método check_output del modulo subprocess. Este proceso solía ser fácil en la versión Python 2.7 pero en Python 3 todo es más complicado y me muestra un UnicodeDecodeError.

Este es el código que envía los bytes:

```
import socket
import subprocess 

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("localhost",7500))

m = subprocess.check_output('ipconfig')
client.send(m)
```

Por supuesto, no es necesario convertirlo a bytes para enviarlo porque la salida de check_output ya entrega valores en formato de bytes.

Hasta hay todo bien, Pero el problema ocurre en el siguiente codigo que recibe los datos ya que no me permite decodificarlo.

El código que recibe los datos es el siguiente:

```
import socket

serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serv.bind(("localhost",7500))
serv.listen(1)

conex,direccion = serv.accept()
a = conex.recv(4096)
print(a.decode('utf-8'))
```

Cuando ejecuto este codigo me muestra el siguiente error: en la ultima linea, en la que dice "print(a.decode('utf-8'))" , El error que me sale es el siguiente:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa2 in position 13: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que retorna `subprocess.check_output` son efectivamente bytes, pero con una codificación determinada, que como todos los programas en modo consola retorna el texto **codificando mediante la página de códigos de 8-bit activa para la consola**, posiblemente cp850.

Lo que puedes hacer es en el cliente decodificar la salida usando la codificación apropiada dependiendo de la página de códigos de CMD y posteriormente codificarla con UTF-8  y enviarla para que en el servidor siempre reciba UTF-8 y pueda obtener el objeto `str` mediante `a.decode('utf-8')`.

```
import socket
import subprocess 

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("localhost", 7500))

m = subprocess.check_output('ipconfig')
m = m.decode("cp850").encode("utf-8")
client.send(m)
```

Comment: Si funciona.  Investigando encontre otro metodo que tambien funciona, usando .decode('utf-8', 'surrogateescape').  Gracias.