# UnicodeDecodeError con sockets en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket, unicode

Tengo un problema en cuanto a `sockets`, el `server.py` esta en una maquina con Windows, y el `client.py` en Linux, al momento de ejecutar el comando `dir`, me da el siguiente error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa3' in position 49: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Intente decodificarlo a `ascii` y me salio el siguiente error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 119: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Ya no se que hacer, ¿Alguna solución?.

Este es el código que causa el problema (`client.py`):

```
data_received = client_socket.recv(2024).decode('ascii').split()
```

De antemano gracias por sus respuestas!

Comment: En cuanto a codificación del mensaje, pues nose, nose mucho sobre esto de codificasion y decodificacion. el comando `dir` lo envio desde el cliente, y el cliente esta en una maquina linux

Comment: `data_received` son los datos recibidos del servidor tanto como del cliente dependiendo si es servidor o cliente

Comment: Supongo que usas subprocess, si envias los datos tal como los recibes del subproceso (bytes) la codificación depende de la codificación de la consola de Windows en tu caso concreto (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/176048/ayuda-con-python-3-unicodedecodeerror-al-recibir-bytes/176086#176086). Prueba con `data_received = client_socket.recv(2024).decode('cp850').split()` en el cliente linux a ver que pasa.

Comment: Ya lo hice pero en cambio me salio otro error, capas tiene que ver con la codificacion: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 9, in <module>
    client_socket.send(input(input_shell).encode('utf-8'))
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'encode```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de estar ejecutando eso en Python 3 y no en Python 2? input_shell supongo que será una cadena...

Comment: Hay perdón, lo estaba ejecutando en python2, ya lo ejecute en python3 con el codigo que me dijiste y me sale el siguiente error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 49-50: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: ¿En qué linea? Eso indica que estás intentando codificar una cadena que no es ASCII como si lo fuera.Te aconsejo codificar cualquier cosa a enviar a UTF-8, decodificarla, enviarla por el socket y en el otro lado codificar usando utf-8. Linux no es un problema, lo normal es que lo recibido de la shell sea UTF-8, Windows es otra historia como señalo en la pregunta anteriormente comentada.En ese caso haz lo que hago en la respuesta a esa pregunta, decodifica usando la codificación de la consola (p.e "cp850"), codifica a UTF-8, envía por el socket y decodifica usando utf-8 en el cliente.

Comment: Eso es lo que hice y me sale ese error... puse exactamente el código que pusiste en el comentario anterior.

Comment: La idea es que todo lo que pase por el socket sea una cadena utf-8 codificada y que al recibir sepamos siempre lo que tenemos, una cadena UTF-8. Luego en el cliente y en el servidor nos preocupamos de pasar lo que queramos enviar a la otra parte a UTF-8 antes. En cuanto al nuevo problema **¿el error es en la misma línea?** La codificación que yo pongo es CP850 no ASCII como dice el error..

Comment: Ya hice la prueba de nuevo y sigue saliendo el mismo error, te prometo que no puse `decode('ascii')` o `encode('ascii')`.

Comment: Por cierto el error no es en la misma linea es en esta: `if data_received: print(' '.join(data_received))`